# Input string was not in a correct format. Textchange problem

Tags: c#

C# CODE
I have a problem with my "Check in" form.
I want to multiply the txtsubtotal and txtadvancepayment.
In textchange if I put number on the txtadvancepayment, the overallresult is correct. But if I clear the txtadvancepayment (Incase when the user puts a wrong value) it would be error. The error says "Input string was not in a correct format."
What should I do?

**My Code downward**

```
int overalltotal = 0;
              int a = Convert.ToInt32(txtsubtotal.Text);      
              int b = Convert.ToInt32(txtadvancepayment.Text);      
              overalltotal = a - b;      
              txttotalbalance.Text = overalltotal.ToString();
```

Comment: Use `tryParse` here `Convert.ToInt32(txtadvancepayment.Text)` insted of `Convert.ToInt32`

Comment: please look up other posts on how to validate and convert text to number. Your number string is not all numbers and because of that you are getting the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty string cannot be parsed as an `int`. As others have mentioned, you can use `int.TryParse` which accepts a string as the first parameter and an `out int` as the second parameter, which holds the parsed value. You could do this:

```c#
int overallTotal = 0;
int a = 0;
int b = 0;

// TryParse returns a bool
// If either of these fails, the variable a or b will keep the default 0 value
int.TryParse(txtSubtotal.Text, out a);
int.TryParse(txtAdvancePayment.Text, out b);

// Sum a and b
overallTotal = a + b;
```

If you want to show an error to the user that one or both fields isn't a valid integer, you can assign a `bool` variable such as `var aIsNumber = int.TryParse(...)` and then check if `aIsNumber` or `bIsNumber` is `false`. If so, then `a` and/or `b` could not be parsed to an `int`.

Comment: You're code is great. Short code and easy to understant. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Int32.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8).

`Int32.Parse` attempts to convert the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent and  returns value indicates whether the operation succeeded. This would mean, in case your textbox is empty or contains a invalid numeric representation, and the method would return false since it would not be able to convert it to `int32`

For example

```
  if(Int32.TryParse(txtsubtotal.Text,out var a) 
                   && Int32.TryParse(txtadvancepayment.Text,out var b))
  {
         // Code which requires a and b  
  }
```